# Não consigo encontrar a minha função no pacote R

Tags: r, packages

Eu fiz uma função no R e incluí ela no meu pacote que fiz. Eu cliquei em clean and rebuild e, logo depois, fiz um check. Além disso, a minha função foi exportada, e ela aparece listada no doc NAMESPACE do pacote. Porém, mesmo assim, quando abro um script novo e tento chamar a função (depois de abrir a library) a função não aparece e o R não consegue encontrá-la, e fica com essa mensagem de erro:

> Error in "my_function"(tbl) : 
>     could not find function "my_function".

Segue o script da função abaixo:

```
#' <descrição
#'
#' @encoding UTF-8
#' @description
#' Esta função distribui os grupos de repetição aninhados em novas linhas
#'
#' @encoding UTF-8
#' @param tble Tabela que contenha Grupo(s) de Repetição.
#'
#' @encoding UTF-8
#' @param separator Separador utilizado entre nomes do(s) Grupo(s) de 
#' Repetição
#' o nome da variável. O valor default é: '/'.
#'
#' @importFrom stringr str_detect
#'
#' @encoding UTF-8
#' @return Tibble contendo valores do(s) Grupo(s) de Repetição reorganizados 
#' @export
#'
#' @author -----------------------------
#' @author -----------------------------
#'
#'

rearrange_nestgroup <- function(tble, separator = '/') {

  final_tble <- rearrange_repgroup(tble)
  tble_colnames <- colnames(final_tble)

  if (any(str_detect(tble_colnames, '\\[\\d{1,6}\\]')) == TRUE) {
    rearrange_nestgroup(final_tble)

  } else {
    return(final_tble)
  } 
}
```

Gostaria de saber se há algo errado no script da função para que ela não seja exportada

obs.: a função rearrange_repgroup está no mesmo pacote com as minhas funções

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Por favor, clique em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/434108/edit) e traduza a pergunta.

Comment: Tente instalar seu pacote com `devtools::install()`

Comment: `if (any(.) == TRUE)` é o mesmo que `if(any(.))`. Não é necessário comparar explicitamente com `TRUE/FALSE` porque o valor de `any` já é um valor lógico.

Comment: Consegui resolver! Fiz de novo o clean e rebuild e depois reinstalei o pacote, funcionou. Obrigado!

Comment: Rui Barradas, não sabia disso, obrigado pela sugestão vou adaptar na função

Comment: Há ainda as funções `isTRUE` e `isFALSE` que podem ser usadas em casos semelhantes (neste caso como já disse não vale a pena). Por exemplo, para testar o output de `help("all.equal")`.